# Adding sasl.jaas.config to Kafka MDB on payara

Tags: java, kafka-consumer-api, payara

@MessageDriven(name = "KafkaMDB", activationConfig = {
@ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "bootstrapServersConfig", propertyValue = "ab-cde-xyz-stage.crb.axxxxx.net:9093"),
@ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "clientId" , propertyValue = "sp-document-processor"),
@ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "groupIdConfig", propertyValue = "AMPSEM.consumerGroup.v1"),
@ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "topics", propertyValue = "teat.topic.any.v2"),
@ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "autoOffsetReset", propertyValue = "earliest"),
@ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "autoCommitInterval", propertyValue = "100"),
@ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "retryBackoff", propertyValue = "1000"),
@ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "keyDeserializer", propertyValue = "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer"),
@ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "valueDeserializer", propertyValue = "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer"),
@ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "pollInterval", propertyValue = "30000"),
@ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "additionalProperties", propertyValue = "ssl.truststore.location=/u01/oracle/application/config/ext/pp.tenant.truststore.jks,"
+ "ssl.truststore.password=12345,ssl.keystore.location= /u01/oracle/application/config/ext/pp.tenant.sr.keystore.jks,ssl.keystore.password=12345,"
+ "sasl.mechanism=SCRAM-SHA-256,security.protocol=SASL_SSL,**sasl.jaas.config=org.apache.kafka.common.security.scram.ScramLoginModule required username\="pp.ampsem.v1" password\="12345**"")
})

Can Anyone help me in adding sasl.jass.config property to KafkaConsumer that I have created using Payara MDB. I am trying as above, but does not work.

Thanks

[image: Syntax error in Eclipse]

Answer (score 0):

I was running into the same issue, it appears someone else was as well and created a contribution to the cloud connectors project, here is the pull request -> https://github.com/payara/Cloud-Connectors/pull/97

The issue arises because of the '=' sign in the sasl.jaas.config parameter, this is used for splitting properties from their value in the kafka connector.

By wrapping the variable value in single quotes, the entire string is taken and the sasl.jaas.config string can be loaded into the system.

```
@MessageDriven(name = "KafkaMDB", activationConfig = {
    @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "additionalProperties", propertyValue = "sasl.jaas.config='org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required username=${sasl.jaas.connection.string} password=${sasl.jaas.connection.secret};'"))
```

Comment: Hi @Urn : Thank you so much for the details. Just one query,the property now looks as below:@ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "additionalProperties",
sasl.jaas.config='org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required username=\"pp.ampsem.v1\" password=\"9pGVnV1aP5M7gohtMTMxi8AeUtJeIZQrBtulhaDPyHlisjsr9DH50KlC7JRJ3v2k\";'")
Does it look correct? 
Also , Could you tell me the version of kafka-rar where this was fixed.

Comment: Hi @Urn : Just an update : giving the username and password without '/' gives compilation issue(syntax error) and giving it as above gives exception too while deploying the code.
I am using version 0.5.0 for kafka rar, I believe the error could be due to incorrect version.

Comment: Just an update trying with Kafka rar 0.6.0 throws this exception :
WARNING: Found illegal properties [sasl.jaas.config, 'org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required username, "pp.ampsem.v1" password, "9pGVnV1aP5M7gohtMTMxi8AeUtJeIZQrBtulhaDPyHlisjsr9DH50KlC7JRJ3v2k";']>

Comment: It appears from your first message you haven't wrapped the property value in double quotes. see below where I have a double quoted just before sasl.jaas.config wrapping the entire string.

`@ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "additionalProperties", "sasl.jaas.config='org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required username="user" password="password";'")`

I would also highly recommend you edit your answers to remove the passwords and user names to include place holders like my responses.

Comment: Hi @Urn, I am adding a lot of properties in the additional property, hence didn't mention the double quotes, this is the full set of property :
@ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "additionalProperties", propertyValue = "ssl.truststore.location=/u01/ext/pp.tenant.truststore.jks, ssl.truststore.password=pswd,ssl.keystore.location= /u01/ext/pp.tenant.sr.keystore.jks,ssl.keystore.password=pswd1,sasl.mechanism=PLAIN,security.protocol=SASL_PLAINTEXT,sasl.jaas.config='org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required username=\"foo\" password=\"bar\";'")

Comment: Hi @Urn :Note that : "sasl.jaas.config='org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required username="foo" password="bar";'" gives syntax error(without / in username and pswd.
Attached the screenshot in the description of the post(on the very top)